# Binary number converted into an integer

Tags: python, binary, radix

I started learning Python recently. I have a problem understanding this:

```
print(int('0b101', 2))
```

I understand that it is a binary number that's going to be converted to an integer. But why the base should be 2? and can somebody explain what is the base? Thank you

Comment: The base is the number of digit you use to display your number. Binary is a base 2 because it uses `0` and `1`, the decimal is base 10 because you use from `0` to `9`

Comment: A binary number literally means a number expressed in base 2. This is the same as a decimal number is a number expressed in base 10. There is no other base that is appropriate.

Comment: Some good reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation#Base_of_the_numeral_system

Comment: Sounds like you need to learn what [binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number) is. BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask] if you want advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says what number system your string is in currently.
In a binary system, you have only two digits, i.e. 1 and 0.
In decimal, you have 10, i.e. 0-9.

See few examples [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/int) on Programiz

I hope it clears something!

Answer (score 3):

If no base is given, `int` *defaults* to base 10, rather than guessing what base the literal is. For example, `0b101` is also a valid hexadecimal literal:

```
>>> int('0b101', 16)
45313
>>> int('0xb101', 16)
45313
```

If you don't want it to be treated as base-10, you have to be explicit about how it *should* be treated.

```
>>> int('0b101', 2)
5
```